# How to check if a button is clicked in JavaScript

Tags: prototypejs

How to check if a button is clicked or not in prototype JavaScript?

```js
$('activateButton').observe('click', function(event) {
  alert(hi);
});
```

The code above is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this button:

```html
<button id="mybutton">Click Me</button>
```

Use this:

```js
$('mybutton').observe('click', function () {
  alert('Hi');
});
```

Tested and works, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aSRvc/).

You might want to encase it in a `document.observe('dom:loaded', function () { })` thingy, to prevent it executing before your page loads.

Also, just an explanation:

The single dollar sign in Prototype selects an element by its id. The `.observe` function is very similar to jQuery's `.on` function, in that it is for binding an event handler to an element.

Also, if you need it to be a permanent 'button already clicked' thingy, try this:

```js
$('mybutton').observe('click', function () {
  var clicked = true;
  window.clicked = clicked;
});
```

And then, if you want to test if the button has been clicked, then you can do this:

```js
if (clicked) {
  // Button clicked
} else {
  // Button not clicked
}
```

This may help if you are trying to make a form, in which you don't want the user clicking multiple times.

How one may do it in jQuery, just for a reference:

```js
$('#mybutton').on('click', function () {
  alert('Hi');
});
```

Note that, the jQuery code mentioned above could also be shortened to:

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
  alert('Hi');
});
```

jQuery is better in Prototype, in that it combines the usage of Prototype's `$` and `$$` functions into a single function, `$`. That is not just able to select elements via their id, but also by other possible css selection methods.

How one may do it with plain JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('mybutton').onclick = function () {
  alert('Hi');
}
```

Just for a complete reference, in case you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I used this
$('mybutton').observe('click', function () {
  var clicked = true;
  window.clicked = clicked;
});

if (clicked) {
  // Button clicked
} else {
  // Button not clicked
}

Now it works fine :)
a

Comment: "jQuery is better in Prototype in..." is very offending and may lead to another holywar;
pure JS example may also use DOM2 addEventListener;
Prototype 1.7+ also has its own `on()` method with event delegation

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('body').delegate('.activateButton', 'click', function(e){
  alert('HI');
});
```

Comment: Since this is jQuery, I might just as well elaborate on it:

`$('button').click(function () {
  alert('hi');
});` This is a quicker way to do the same task.